# Save Image file in Document Directory and Fetch Image file from it and show on View in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have tried to save image file in document directory and get the file to show on view through imageView. But after saving image, when I fetch image from document directory I am getting value null.

```
- (IBAction)showImage:(id)sender {

    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSLog(@"path: %@", path);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"documentsDirectory: %@", documentsDirectory);
    NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"nature1.jpg"];
    NSLog(@"imagePath: %@", imagePath);
    NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
//    NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath]];
    [imgData writeToFile: imagePath atomically: YES];
    NSLog(@"imgData: %@", imgData);
    UIImage *showImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
//    DocumentDirectoryImage.image = showImg;
}



Getting value on console : 
imagePath: /Users/vikas.patil/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/88A6BD16-9A62-4D9D-9852-5EA2E374060A/data/Containers/Data/Application/16083D44-0BFD-4CE6-8D4E-06A51EB908C1/Documents/nature1.jpg
2019-08-12 13:17:07.173 Assignment15[2270:107222] imgData: (null)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please first save image in document directory then try to get the data from same link.
Your code will look like after little changes.

```
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSLog(@"path: %@", path);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"documentsDirectory: %@", documentsDirectory);
        NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"nature1.jpg"];
        NSLog(@"imagePath: %@", imagePath);

    //    NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath]];
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage);
        [imageData writeToFile: imagePath atomically: YES];
        NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
        NSLog(@"imgData: %@", imgData);
        UIImage *showImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
```

Comment: how to save image file in document directory?

Comment: first convert image object to data with this 
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage);    
[imgData writeToFile: imagePath atomically: YES];

Comment: I use this, now my code like this.  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nature1.jpg"];
    NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
I written on top of the code now on console showing object data of image